# export 'cordova' (imported as 'cordova') was not found in '@ionic-native/core'

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, ionic-native

I have a problem with @ionic-native/printer

```
     ./node_modules/@ionic-native/printer/__ivy_ngcc__/ngx/index.js:30:67-74 - 
        Error: export 'cordova' (imported as 'cordova') was not found in '@ionic-native/core' 
    (possible exports: Cordova, CordovaCheck, CordovaFunctionOverride, CordovaInstance, CordovaProperty, ERR_CORDOVA_NOT_AVAILABLE,
 ERR_PLUGIN_NOT_INSTALLED, InstanceCheck, InstanceProperty, IonicNativePlugin, Plugin, checkAvailability, cordovaWarn, get, getPlugin, getPromise, instanceAvailability, overrideFunction, pluginWarn, wrap, wrapEventObservable, wrapInstance)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eTciH.png)

i did :

```
`$ npm install cordova-plugin-printer`

 $ npm install @ionic-native/printer
```

https://bobcares.com/blog/printing-with-ionic-application/

Comment: did you find any solution to this problem? I have the same issue with @ionic-native/open-native-settings

Answer (score 1):

Try updating your printer and core to the same version. I had a similar problem and I solved it like this.

npm install @ionic-native/printer@latest
npm install  @ionic-native/core@latest
ionic cap sync